# IE8 not displaying images uniformly within divs

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

My site consists of 5 divs (represented by green boxes). There should be 3 per row, and you can view my demo site here:
http://testsite24.netai.net/public/demo2.html

My issue is that IE8 does not display the images within each div, in the same way. Here is a screenshot showing them displaying **correctly** in IE9:

[image: ie9]

and here is them displaying **incorrectly** in IE8:

[image]

the html for one of the divs (green boxes) is:

```
<a href="http://www.demo.com/adfadfadfa">
   <div class="block personal fl">
   <div class="content">
   <p class="price">
<p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg)"></p>
   </p>
     </div>

    <ul class="features">
<li class="titlebox">adfadfadf </li>
<li>adfadfadf</li>
<li>adfadfadf</li>
    </ul>
     </div>              
</a>
```

You can see the image is produced with this line:

```
<p class="vignette" style="background-image:url(http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg)"></p>
```

and the class "vignette" is used to provide the feather effect around the image. However, this doesn't seem supported in IE8
so on the conditional style sheet for ie8, I simply use

```
.vignette {
    }
```

and that's why there's no feather effect in the IE8 screenshot.

However, why does IE8 not display the images the same way? The entire .vignette css code is:

```
.vignette {
       width: 90%;
       margin-left:auto;
       margin-right:auto;
       margin-bottom:-5%;
        box-shadow: 15px 15px 40px #A1F997 inset,-15px -15px 40px #A1F997 inset;
        height: 290px;
        background-size: cover;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }
```

Any help would be amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, `background-size` is a CSS3 proprierty, and do not work in IE8, but you can achieve it with something like (image must be defined into CSS):

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale');

-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(
src='http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f8/Ellen_H._Swallow_Richards_House_Boston_MA_01.jpg',
sizingMethod='scale')";
```

But since that's not what you want, maybe this helps:

http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/